# 'adb not installed' error when trying to take a snapshot with uiautomatorviewer

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, ui-automation

I used the uiautomatorviewer to do UI android automation. But when i try to take snapshot to list the UI, it shows adb is not installed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See the answer at https://plus.google.com/u/0/108487870030743970488/posts/2TrMqs1ZGQv

Basically, the `com.android.uiautomator.bindir` property is not set in `uiautomatorviewer.bat`.

Edit the file and set the property to the path for android-sdk/tools folder.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem with new twist: com.android.uiautomator.bindir was set to `C:\Users\Matti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\bin`. I changed it to `C:\Users\Matti\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools` and now it works again.

Answer (score 3):

Edit files last line with below path:

> call %java_exe% -Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs%
>   -Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir=H:\android-sdk\tools -jar %jarpath% %

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying the .bat file and it works, but it is important that the tools path is with the "\" character closing, but will not work, example
call "%java_exe%" "-Djava.ext.dirs=%javaextdirs%" "-Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir="C:\Android_SDK\tools\" -jar %jarpath% %*

Answer (score 0):

I followed the link: https://plus.google.com/u/0/108487870030743970488/posts/2TrMqs1ZGQv
and editted the last line of uiautomatorviewer.bat file but the issue still persisted.

In my case I removed the existing android SDK and reinstalled it via Android Studio and it worked. The new Android SDK does not have a UI for SDK manager and hence its is a hassle to figure out which packages are needed to be installed.

Once the Android Studio is installed it automatically installs the Android SDK and all the required packages for the uiautomatorviewer to work perfectly.